# Error AIR 33 for Android when INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113

Tags: android, air, apk, adobe

I'm currently trying to compile the 64 bit version of an AIR application, but I get the following error when trying to test with a Samsung J6+ device. [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113].
I'm using the latest Harman AIR 33.0.2.315 SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Seems your app contains native extensions that contains only armv7 but not armv8 libraries. Please check if your ANEs was built with AIR 33 and contains armv8 (64-bit) version of native libraries inside.

Answer (score 0):

According to this
https://github.com/airsdk/Adobe-Runtime-Support/issues/65
you're supposed to edit the adt.jar file to explicitly use the armv8 setting.

After publishing your x32 app (1.0.0), bump up the version number incrementally (e.g 1.0.1) and then edit your adt.cfg file to uncomment these lines to use the armv8 architecture.

```
DefaultArch=armv8
OverrideArch=armv8
DebugOut=false
```

Then, just to be sure, set Adobe Animate Publish settings to use x64. It should publish without error. You should now have two APKs, one 32-bit, the other 64-bit.